# WOT Mastery Badges Mechanics

Tags: world-of-tanks

The World of Tanks Master badges are awarded for earning more experience in a battle than 50% (3rd class) 80% (2nd Class) 90% (1st class) and 99% (Ace tanker) of recent players in that tank.

Do those figures take into account bonuses? In other words is the score that is matched against other players include the 2x 3x etc for first win of the day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in the following screenshot, in the battle results "Received" is only the base amount. No boosters or special bonuses count. The mastery badge is based on this amount (experimentally proved). Also, whenever the "Total" amount is counted, it is specified in mission criteria.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, only base experience is used for calculating mastery badges.

Comment: Could you find me a reference for this?

Answer (score 2):

Only base XP is counted for mastery badges.

Although not currently documented on the WoT wiki's [Achievements page](https://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Achievements#Mastery_Badges) you can find references in various places, for example The [Tank Mastery Missions for April 2019](https://worldoftanks.com/en/content/guide/tank-mastery-missions/tmm-0419/) page requires winning an Ace Tanker Mastery Badge (my bold below):

> Earn more **Base XP** in a single battle than the highest average Base XP earned in a single battle by 99% of players of that same tank within the past seven days.